# Web page that don't scroll with a navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm facing a problem that after many hours of try and retry I cannot solve.
I would like to prepare a page for a web application that fill the browser page without scrolling that has a navbar and two column (one section on the left and one one the right).
This is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column px-0">
        <div class="dpHeader">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-custom py-0">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img src="~/images/icon-64.png" style="height: 48px;" alt="Brand" />
                    My Application Name
                </a>
                <div>Name and Surname</div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex px-0">
            <div class="dpPanelSx bg-info vh-100">Panel Sx</div>
            <div class="dpPanelDx">Panel Dx</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
/* set custom color for the nav bar*/
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #034c67; /*#213B52;*/
}
    /* change the brand and text color */
    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-text {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    }
    /* change the link color */
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    }
    /* change the color of active or hovered links */
    .navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
    .navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .dpHeader {
        flex: 1;
    }

    .dpPanelSx {
        flex: 1;
    }

    .dpPanelDx {
        flex: 1;
    }

    .dpUserName {
        flex: 1;
    }
```

But the height of the two column oversize the browser window and the scroll bar appear.
How can I modify my code to obtain my goal?

Thanks

Comment: Your CSS seems to miss a lot of classes called in your HTML. It's hard to say what happens if we don't know what the other CSS rules the classes carry.

Comment: Sorry, I'm usign bootstrap 4.

Comment: In that case, remember to add it as a tag for your next question. It's faster to get answers when the frameworks involved are tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply don't want to ever scroll, you can set `overflow-y:hidden` in the style for the body. So in your CSS for the `body, html` part, simply append

`overflow:hidden`

and you shouldn't see the scrollbar anymore

Comment: Thank you, it works :-) But why if the two columns and the navbar are in the outer container that has height:100%, overflow?

Comment: @robyg72 because by default the body and html nodes have a slight margin of a few pixels down and to the right. If you wanted to fix that, you can alternatively add, in the body,html definiton, `margin:0`, which should snap everything to the very top, without needing to hide the scrollar, and if you later wanted to give them a slight margin, then you can first give a margin, say, 5px, then for the height, instead of setting it to 100%, set it to `calc(100%-5px)`, for example, if that makes sense

Comment: @robyg72 also if it was helpful to solve your issue, i would appreciate it if you could kindly click the check mark on the answer when you get a chance